# Which information is used to sort default view?

Tags: 2013, task-list

In a task list I can simply use the quick edit grid to change the order of the tasks and further more ident them.

Internally the id of the item does not change even though it was moved e.g. from the last position to the first using the button in the ribbon.

Can someone tell me how this information is stored internally because the default view does not have sorting activated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hidden fields named "Order" and "ParentID" that are used for that purpose. As you move the items (up/down, indent/outdent) in the view of a tasks list the values of these fields are updated.

Comment: Thanks. This is the information I was looking for. I was already aware of "ParentID" but did not know "Order" because it is not displayed e.g. when using the REST api.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean for "internally". All informations are stored in a SQL database, but you better do not manipulate it!
Why don't you simply use the column you want (or add a new one if you need it) to sort activating sorting in the default view?

Comment: There is no visible property which causes the sort order in the default view. But I would like to know which internal property of a SPListItem is used to sort the default view.

Comment: That is the ID given by the system, there is no way to modify it. It is an INT number. A list/library is sorted by ID just until you decide to sort it in another way - and you can do it whenever you want, even in default view.

Comment: Did you already use the possibility to move tasks up/down? Then you will see that the sort order is not based on the internal ID afterwards.

Comment: I still don't understand your point. A task list is not so special. Move up or down a task is just a question of view. If you mean to prioritize them, then it is the "due date" the column you need. Please be clearer about what you need to do.